# Im getting the error = Use of undeclared type 'Tableview' I am not sure why?

Tags: swift, tableview

```
import UIKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate{


    @IBOutlet var search: UISearchBar!

    @IBOutlet var Tableview: UIView!


    var items = ["hello"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }




    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return items.count
    }


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
        var cell: Tableview.deqeueReusableCellWithIdentifier;("cell")

  //Error = Undeclared type 'Tableview'

        cell.textLabel?.text = self.items[indexPath.row]
        return cell;


}



}
```

Comment: I'm not a Swift programmer, but maybe you have a typo? Could it be `UITableView` or `TableView`?

Answer (score 2):

Replace the colon (`:`) with the equal sign and you'll be ok:

```
var cell = Tableview.deqeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell")
```

On another note, even though Xcode won't give you an error about it, you shouldn't begin your variable with a capital. The convention is that starting capitals should be to indicate class names.

Comment: Now I'm getting Value of type 'UIView' has no member 'deqeueReusableCellWithIdentifier'

Comment: Have you realized there's a spelling mistake in your code?

Comment: Sorry not UIView I mean UITableView

Comment: Where is the spelling mistake

Comment: It should be `dequeue...` instead of `deqeue`. Please check the documentation